# File download with content-disposition set still shows "untitled file" in browser

Tags: asp.net, http, download, http-headers

I'm writing a controller method in ASP.NET WebAPI to download a file. Here's the part where I set the headers and content:

```
result.Content = new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(csvResult));
result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/csv");
result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = fileName;
result.Content.Headers.ContentLength = csvResult.Length;
```

The file is being downloaded, but the browser always shows it as "untitled file". Fiddler shows the request coming back with the correct headers:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Report2015-9_createtest3.csv
Content-Length: 1477
Content-Type: text/csv
```

I've tried it with the content-type as "application/octet-stream" and "text/plain" and those don't work any better either. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: This probably isn't caused by your controller method. Most likely you need to specify the title in the file you're trying to download.